# What does SetHandler "proxy:unix:..." do?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, unix

What does the Apache "proxy:unix:..." handler do, and where is it documented? I see it used here and there, like:

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:..."
```

For example in [this recent question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041507/filesmatch-or-sethandler-directive-does-not-get-applied), or in the [SetHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler) and [mod_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples)  documentation.

I can guess that it might pipe to a Unix socket, but what about the syntax in the [mod_fcgi example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples)? Where's the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the docs for [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> In 2.4.7 and later, support for using a Unix Domain Socket is available by using a target which prepends unix:/path/lis.sock|. For example, to proxy HTTP and target the UDS at /home/www.socket, you would use `unix:/home/www.socket|http://localhost/whatever/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the  [sethandler directive documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler):

This describes the use of Apache's [handlers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/handler.html)

Comment: Thanks. My question is specifically about the "proxy:unix:..." handler. I'll try to make that clearer.